# OpenCV Stereo Calibration and triangulation in a user defined coordinate system

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera, camera-calibration

How do you stereo cameras so that the output of the triangulation is in a real world coordinate system, that is defined by known points?

OpenCV stereo calibration returns results based on the pose of the left hand camera being the reference coordinate system.

I am currently doing the following:

Intrinsically calibrating both the left and right camera using a chess board. This gives the Camera Matrix A, and the distortion coefficients for the camera.

Running stereo calibrate, again using the chessboard, for both cameras. This returns the extrinsic parameters, but they are relative to the cameras and not the coordinate system I would like to use.

How do I calibrate the cameras in such a way that known 3D point locations, with their corresponding 2D pixel locations in both images provides a method of extrinsically calibrating so the output of triangulation will be in my coordinate system?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a rigid transform estimation between the coordinate system in which your object is referenced and the coordinates as estimated by triangulation? I would suggest looking into this reference http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate disparity map from the stereo camera - you may use cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM
2. After finding the disparity map, refer this: [OpenCv depth estimation from Disparity map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211190/opencv-depth-estimation-from-disparity-map)

Comment: How will that be in my coordinate system?