# calculate distance based on disparity map

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to program a robot that detect obstacles and estimate distance.
I am using computer vision for this task . I calculated the disparity map but I do not know how to detect obstacles and estimate the distance. 
what are the steps I need to follow to accomplish this goal?
what are the Open CV's functions I will need to use?
Is there any source codes?

Comment: you should look at the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211190/opencv-depth-estimation-from-disparity-map

Comment: The question is too broad. There are many variables that depend on the environment and application at hand. You won't get a magic answer to what you are trying to do here. Maybe split the question into parts, or be more specific.

Comment: the answer that i need is in the following form:
if I was asking about single camera calibration , the answer would be:
1)  Take set of images for the chessboard from different viewpoints.
2)  detects the corners of this chessboard pattern , by using cvFindChessboardCorners()
3) detect sub pixel corners , by using cvFindCornerSubPix()
4) calibrate the camera , by using cvCalibrateCamrera2

I need to know the steps that i have to follow to get the distance from the disparity map. do i need to segment the objects? if yes, then what?
what are the functions I need to use?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418846/reprojectimageto3d-in-opencv